# stripe-payment displaying only image for product

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripes

I am new to stripe api And updating created product from api
https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/update?lang=java
from the docs it is cleared that for images
A list of up to 8 URLs of images for this product, meant to be displayable to the customer. When I passing 3 images urls in array using java api, response was successful
But when I go back to stripe dashboard it is displaying only 1 image.
I just want to know that if one image is displaying then why list of images is there.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe only uses the first image in the list for products like Checkout and the dashboard. The API accepts a list of images despite only using the first one for future Stripe products.